# How to pass tab key followed by down arrow key in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a code that logins to a webpage and tries to download a file. but after login and before downloading it requires selecting a particular report "Pass Loan Market" through the radio button window, can anyone pls assist with what could be done here? I am thinking to do this by pressing the tab key twice and then clicking on the down arrow key and finally clicking on the download button but the code I have written is not working. can you please help?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import Actionchains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.osaka.com"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys("*****")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("******")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "button"))).click()
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.Tab*2).perform()
```

Comment: As previously, your code here is not performing the login action so we are missing basic debugging abilities here

Comment: In case you want to give me the credentials - yes, currently I'm here :)

Comment: can you pls try to login now and help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with use of XPath.
You can locate the parent `tr` element based on the text of child `td` and then access the second child - the `input`.
I hope you saw these elements are inside the iframe. You need to switch into it in order to access elements there and to switch back to default content when you want to access elements out of it.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

url = "https://www.google.com/home/index.jsp#LOANS.DOWNLOAD.download"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[type='email']"))).send_keys("***")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submitBtn"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[type='password']"))).send_keys("***")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submit"))).click()

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "MFrame")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr[./td[text()='xyz file']]//input"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='downloadButton']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thankyou so much prophet- really appreciate your time and effort

Comment: i will learn more about xpath

Comment: You are welcome! XPath is most powerful way to locate elements. Most people not enough familiar with it

Comment: Hi @Prophet, can you also pls confirm if is it possible to change the file name before downloading from the wesbsite like i need to add the date as well in the file name + also need to change the download directory ? is it possible in selenium ?

Comment: AFAIK you can only change the file name when it is already downloaded to your computer. Also it is possible to change the folder where files are downloaded to, but many people have problems with it so I prefer to download the file to it default downloading folder, then rename it if needed and move or copy it to some other folder you need